# Signs from Hashem

Tags: halacha

Is one allowed to make a sign if there is no one around them, which can guide and help them, except Hashem.

If one is allowed to make a sign, are they allowed to believe in it and make life changing decisions with these signs.

For example if you are no sure if you shuld marry someone or take a job and you ask Hashem for a sign in order to determine your future, like what Elizer did or we should not make a sign all together?

Comment: What do you mean by 'make a sign'?

Comment: @DoubleAA http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/L@Chin-ThumbBack_Squeeze http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/BentB@Sfhead

Comment: I suspect one's not allowed to make the sign of the cross, or at least not if one means it. (CYLOR.) A stop sign should be okay; if you've posted it, you should certainly make decisions based on it, and those may be life-changing, or at least life-preserving. Can you [edit] into the question what you're asking about, please?

Comment: when Rivka was unsure about the meaning of her difficult pregnancy, she went to ask the prophet Shem. We don't have prophecy in our time, but the next best thing is to ask the gadol hador.

Answer (score 4):

The gemara in Taanis 4a says that Eliezer, Avraham's servant, when he was by the water cistern and asked for a sign, acted improperly.

> א"ר שמואל בר נחמני אמר רבי יונתן שלשה שאלו שלא כהוגן לשנים השיבוהו כהוגן לאחד השיבוהו שלא כהוגן ואלו הן אליעזר עבד אברהם ושאול בן קיש ויפתח הגלעדי אליעזר עבד אברהם

Eliezer had no one else to ask, as he was alone by the well, far from his mentor, in a land of idol worshipers, and yet his asking was viewed as improper.